# React setInterval question (using setState inside another setState problem)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval, use-state

I'm new to reactjs; I encountered this problem while studying about `useState`. I'm trying to decrease the value of the second state when the first state decreases to 0, and the iteration will run until both states are 0. But the second state always decreases by 2, which makes me confused.
This is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [firstCount,setFirstCount]=useState(10);
  const [secondCount,setSecondCount] = useState(5);

  function decreaseCount(){
    const interval= setInterval(()=>{
    setFirstCount((prevFirstCount)=>{
      if(prevFirstCount>0){
        return prevFirstCount-1;
      }
      else{
        setSecondCount((prevSecondCount)=>{
          if(prevSecondCount>0){
            return prevSecondCount-1
          }
          else{
          clearInterval(interval);
          return prevFirstCount
          }
        })
      return 10;
      }
    })
  },1000)
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div>{firstCount}</div>
     <div>{secondCount}</div>
      <button onClick={(decreaseCount)}>Decrease Count</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/interval-setcountprob-plpzl?file=/src/App.js:0-835

I'd really appreciate if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the callback you pass to `setFirstCount` must be pure, but you violated that contract by trying to use it to mutate `secondCount`. You can correctly implement this dependency with `useRef` and `useEffect`:

```
export default function App() {
  const [firstCount, setFirstCount] = useState(0);
  const [secondCount, setSecondCount] = useState(6);

  const firstCountRef = useRef(firstCount);
  const secondCountRef = useRef(secondCount);

  firstCountRef.current = firstCount;
  secondCountRef.current = secondCount;

  function decreaseCount() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (secondCountRef.current === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
      }

      const { current } = firstCountRef;

      setFirstCount(prev => (prev + 9) % 10);
      setSecondCount(prev => current > 0 ? prev : (prev + 9) % 10);
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div>{firstCount}</div>
     <div>{secondCount}</div>
      <button onClick={decreaseCount}>Decrease Count</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, it might be easier to use a single state and compute the counts from that:

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(60);
  const countRef = useRef(count);
  const firstCount = count % 10;
  const secondCount = Math.floor(count / 10);

  countRef.current = count;

  function decreaseCount() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (countRef.current === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
      }

      setCount(prev => prev - 1);
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div>{firstCount}</div>
     <div>{secondCount}</div>
      <button onClick={decreaseCount}>Decrease Count</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions I'll try to work out this way, really appriciate it !!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue this way :

```
  const [firstCount, setFirstCount] = useState(10);
  const [secondCount, setSecondCount] = useState(5);

  const handleDecrease = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setFirstCount((prev) => {
        if (prev > 0) {
          return prev - 1;
        }
        if (prev === 0) {
          return prev + 10;
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (firstCount === 0) {
      setSecondCount((prev) => {
        if (prev === 0) {
          setFirstCount((firstPrev) => firstPrev + 10);
          return prev + 5;
        } else {
          return prev - 1;
        }
      });
    }
  }, [firstCount]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{firstCount}</div>
      <div>{secondCount}</div>
      <button onClick={handleDecrease}>Decrease Count</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but i have to clear the interval at the end to stop it or add a button to reset the count without having two interval running at the same time

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't declare functions like this:

```
function decreaseCount(){
...
```

Instead you should use `useCallback`:

```
const decreaseCount = useCallback(() => {
//your code here
}[firstCount, secondCount]) //dependency array
```

You should read more about hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html